# Converting old-style Idris proofs to elaborator scripts

Tags: idris

What would be some of the recommended guidelines for converting the old-style Idris proofs to the new elaborator reflection-based ones?

I have a substantial amount of Idris code written in the old (pre-ER) style and, while some of the tactics translate to the new style relatively easily, I'm having a bit of a hard time converting since I'm doing a lot of it by trial and error. I'm not aware of docs outlining such a procedure, so I'd be very grateful for any tips. TIA.